# What is the correct encoding for passing parameter to TokensRegex

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am getting an exception when calling the TokensRegex using REST API with the following pattern:

```
([{word:/by/}][{tag:NN}]+)(/and|,/[{tag:NN}|{tag:VBG}]*)*
```

However, when I use the Web interface to call the TokensRegex against the same local server, I got the correct response. I am assuming that the web interface does the encoding to the pattern before calling the rest api.

In my java program, I have encoded the parameter with "UTF-8" but I got the exception.

Any help will be appreciated.

The exception is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$TokensRegexHandler.lambda$null$365(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:814)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.object(JSONOutputter.java:453)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.routeObject(JSONOutputter.java:352)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.lambda$object$344(JSONOutputter.java:467)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$TokensRegexHandler.lambda$null$366(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:808)
```

Comment: Showing your actuall code usually makes it easier to get good answers

Answer (score 0):

I used this command and it returned the matched text without any errors:

```
wget --post-data 'The car drove down the street.' 'localhost:9000/tokensregex?pattern=(/car/ [{pos:VBD}] )'
```